# EWS - how do I find all incomplete tasks?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Services to try to get a list of all Outlook tasks which are not complete.

I have an instance of ExchangeService, and attempt to find all incomplete tasks like this:

```
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsNotEqualTo(TaskSchema.Status, TaskStatus.NotStarted);
FindItemsResults<Item> tasks = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, searchFilter, view);
```

However, on the last line, I get a "ServiceResponseException: The specified value is invalid for property." This seems weird to me because [the EWS documentation explicitly states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.task.status%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) that the Task.Status is supposed to be one of the TaskStatus enumeration values. Creating a SearchFilter which compares against a string value does not cause an exception, but I haven't tried any of the other enumeration options to see whether they give the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to do this using ExtendedPropertyDefinition with Exchange 2007.

I am using [PidLidTaskComplete Canonical Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc839514.aspx).

Full list of named properties available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815492.aspx).

```
//Create the extended property definition.
ExtendedPropertyDefinition taskCompleteProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x0000811C, MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
//Create the search filter.
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(taskCompleteProp, false);                    
//Get the tasks.
FindItemsResults<Item> tasks = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, filter, new ItemView(50));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may also achieve that without using any magic numbers:

```
var view = new ItemView(20);
var query = new SearchFilter.IsNotEqualTo(TaskSchema.IsComplete, true);
var results = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, query, view);
```

This does work on a *certain* version of exchange :)