# filtering on task status using EWS via a webservice call

Tags: web-services, soap, outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to query Exchange Webservices for incomplete tasks, but unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823489/ews-how-do-i-find-all-incomplete-tasks) I'm doing so using a plain webservice call (like via SOAP-UI) and not via C#.

I want to know if I can filter on the same thing using a simple webservice request.

My current request gets all outlook tasks, and I can filter the results, but it would be preferable to let Exchange do the filtering.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <FindItem Traversal="Shallow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
         <ItemShape>
            <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
         </ItemShape>
         <ParentFolderIds>
            <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="tasks">
               <t:Mailbox>
                  <t:EmailAddress>dummy@address.com</t:EmailAddress>
               </t:Mailbox>
            </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
         </ParentFolderIds>
      </FindItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm talking to Outlook 2007.

Comment: Can't you do something with SearchFolders? See e.g. chapter 15 of the Sterling book "Inside Microsoft® Exchange Server 2007 Web Services". This is a must-have book if you're doing raw EWS SOAP.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will look into it! Because I'm the developer on the client side, in all honesty doing something on the server side didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the best practice here is that you do client-side filtering. If you are making infrequent ad hoc requests for incomplete tasks, then I suggest you use a search filter. If you find that you have to make many frequent requests for updated tasks, then a search folder might be appropriate. If you want to make your application real time, you could subscribe to event notifications on the tasks folder.

By the way, is your application accessing many mailboxes or just a single user's mailbox? You example above indicates that this is a delegate access scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In answer to your question: I'm building a portlet / widget that will retrieve the open (outlook and other) tasks for the currently logged in user (potentially freqent queries for multiple users). At this time we use the delegate assess scenario, but in the future we want to use a SSO solution, possibly using ADFS / SAML 2.0.